# Stonestreet One's Bluetopia how do you request a MTU change?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

Or more specifically how do you request an MTU change when operating at the "Platform Manager" level?

## More details

- I'm using the sample program `LinuxGATM_CLT` which acts as a GATT client and it uses the Bluetopia Platform Manager Framework.
- I'm using TI's WL183xMOD WiLink hardware which uses Bluetopia (previously owned by Stonestreet One).

## The API call exists

The function exists, but seems to be at stack layer lower than the PM:

```
~/src/ti_bluetopia/ $  grep GATT_Exchange_MTU_Request ./BluetopiaPM/Bluetopia/include/GATTAPI.h

BTPSAPI_DECLARATION int BTPSAPI GATT_Exchange_MTU_Request(unsigned int BluetoothStackID, unsigned int ConnectionID, Word_t RequestedMTU, GATT_Client_Event_Callback_t ClientEventCallback, unsigned long CallbackParameter);
```

## But its not callable from the "Platform Manager" level

Everything within `BluetopiaPM/sample/LinuxGATM/LinuxGATM_CLT.c` uses `GATM` functions from `BluetopiaPM/include/client/GATMAPI.h`

It feels like the `GATT_Exchange_MTU_Request()` function has not been exposed at the PM level.  Its hard to dig deeper into how the PM works because they only ship binaries (doesn't seem to be open-source).  For example the only match is the `GATTAPI.h` header file and a binary library file:

```
~/src/ti_bluetopia/ $  grep -ri GATT_Initialize ./
Binary file ./BluetopiaPM/Bluetopia/lib/libSS1BTGAT.a matches
```

I feel like the solution is to find methods to report my current Platform Manager `BluetoothStackID`, `ConnectionID`, and callback parameters so that I can call the `GATT_Exchange_MTU_Request()` function directly.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the workaround is to get an earlier version of Stonestreet One's Bluetopia, before they created the "Platform Manager".  These earlier versions (suchas 4.012 and 4.013) don't have the advantage of the Platform Manager, but they do allow you to have more control, operating at a lower level where you can call:

`GATT_Initialize()` and

`GATT_Exchange_MTU_Request()`

One good example is 4.013's `SPPLEDemo.c` which calls the above-mentioned methods.